# Problemas con dynamic_cast: la clase no es polimórfica

Tags: c++

No soy capaz de compilar el siguiente fragmento de código:

```
struct Base
{
  int valor;

  Base()
    : valor(1)
  { }
};

struct Hija : Base
{
  int func()
  { return valor; }
};

int main()
{
  Base* punteroBase = new Hija;
  Hija* punteroHija = dynamic_cast<Hija*>(punteroBase);
  std::cout << punteroHija->func();
}
```

El error que me aparece es el siguiente:

```
main.cpp:21:54: error: cannot dynamic_cast 'punteroBase' (of type 'struct Base*') to type 'struct Hija*' (source type is not polymorphic)
```

Viendo el código queda claro que ambas clases están relacionadas vía herencia y sin embargo `dynamic_cast` no funciona.

¿A qué se debe este problema? ¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tu clase base no tiene ningún método virtual, y por tanto no es polimórfica, y solamente las clases polimórficas son las que generan una `vtable` (la tabla que guarda, por cada dirección de memoria en tiempo de ejecución, el tipo derivado con el que se creó el objeto, necesario para el `dynamic_cast`).

Si no necesitas que ninguna función en particular sea virtual, puedes hacer virtual al destructor:

```
struct Base
{
    virtual ~Base() = default;
};
```

Si no necesitas que tu objeto sea polimórfico (para ahorrate una `vtable` para una clase que en realidad no la necesita), y conoces el tipo derivado, sustitúyelo por un `static_cast` y ya está:

```
Hija* punteroHija = static_cast<Hija*>(punteroBase);
```

Para esto nunca hagas un `reinterpret_cast`, porque los `static_cast` tienen en cuenta posibles diferencias de alineamiento y el `reinterpret_cast` no, aunque en eficiencia son iguales.